# SharePoint - Problem provisioning a master page through a solution/feature

Tags: sharepoint

I cannot find out why a master page is not being provisioned to /_catalogs/masterpage as (I suppose) I'm directing it.

Here are the relevant snippets:

.ddf:

```
;*** Master page
..\..\..\Feature\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ADS\MasterPage.xml ADS\MasterPage.xml
..\..\..\Feature\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ADS\MasterPages\ADS.master ADS\ADS.master
```

MasterPage.xml:

```
<Module Name="MasterPages" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Url="ADS.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
</Module>
```

Feature.xml

```
<ElementManifest Location="MasterPage.xml" />
```

I expect ADS.master to end up in http://mySite/_catalogs/masterpage, but it doesn't.

Ideas, appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note: I looked already at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031418/sharepoint-file-provisioning-not-working) post, but I'm manually editing these files. Maybe what I'm looking for is how those files look after gen'ed by WSPBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you activate the feature?

Did you check if the feature files end up in the right place in the 12 hive?

WSPBuilder does not do anything with these files, it just packages them for you.. you shouldnt have to use a ddf?

Comment: Good one ArjanP. what happened? I was provisioning a feature through a solution and creating a site and list from their respective templates. I assumed that, since I was able to do that, then feature has been activated, but it was not! I activated the feature and it seemed to work. Thanks!